# How can I do when redis is down?

Tags: spring-boot, redis

There I have many `spring-boot` service depends on a redis to generate a continuous id `such as 1,2,3...`

How can I do when redis is down?

extra:

1. one `Redis`, not `master-slave`
2. Does `Redis` persistence keep data from being lost?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Redis to persist data on disk, i.e. AOF and RDB format. However, since the persistence is asynchronous (with AOF, you can sync your write for every operation, but in that way, you'll have performance problems), you still might loose data.

In your case, it seems that you might use the `INCR` command to generate id. If Redis is down without dumping all data, you'll get duplicate ids when Redis restarts.

This problem cannot be solved, even if you have a master-replica setup, since the synchronization between master and replica is also asynchronous.

Comment: I have saved `id` in `MySQL`. So I can only stop the service, write the `id` to redis, and then restart the service?